# Implementing a generic conversion from an object implementing the `Error` trait

Tags: rust

I cannot get the following code to compile.

- I get an error that `From` is already implemented.
- If I remove the manual impl of `From` I get the error that `From` is not implemented.
- If I do not implement `Error` it works fine.

I suppose that this is due to the blank impl `impl<T> From<T> for T` in core. How should I work around this? Not implementing `Error` is not really an option.

Code ([playground](http://is.gd/6kxEM6))

```
use std::fmt;
use std::io;
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum ErrorType {
    Other(Box<Error>)
}

impl fmt::Display for ErrorType {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt.write_str("not implemented")
    }
}

impl Error for ErrorType {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        use self::ErrorType::*;
        match *self {
            Other(ref err) => err.description(),
        }
    }
}

impl<E: Error + 'static> From<E> for ErrorType {
    fn from(other: E) -> Self {
        ErrorType::Other(Box::new(other))
    }
}

fn ret_io_err() -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    Ok(())
}

fn ret_error_type() -> Result<(), ErrorType> {
    try!(ret_io_err());
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.

That implementation would be a bit useless, anyway.  It would mean that *all* other error types would just be immediately boxed.  At that point, you might as well just make use of the existing conversions involving `Box<Error>` and use *that* instead.

If you want an error type that actually *preserves* the type of the unified errors, you'll need to implement `From` once for each of them.  The [`error-type`](https://crates.io/crates/error-type) crate can help with defining unifying error types.

Comment: Well, catching all Error is the whole point of such a generic implementation. Unfortunately there is no existing impl I can use. That would only work if I would always want to return `Box<Error>`. For now I use use `map_err` to wrap it at every call site.

Comment: @Ferio: The problem is that *even if you could* write that impl, it would immediately prevent you from *ever* implementing more specific logic for any other type.  Your `ErrorType` enum would *literally* be the same as `Box<Error>`.  You don't need to use `map_err`, you just need to write a `From` impl for every source error type, which is what `error-type` was designed for.

Comment: True…I didn’t consider how `try!` is implemented. Seems that a catch-all is not possible.

Comment: it wouldn't be literally the same, you can't impl foreign traits for Box<>

Answer (score 0):

According comments above I've found this one approach works only:

```
impl<T: error::Error + 'static> From<Box<T>> for Error {
    fn from(e: Box<T>) -> Self {
        Error::Other(e)
    }
}
```

To use it you should `Box` errors:

```
try!(any_result().map_err(Box::new))
```

But if you need generic error (for user-defined tasks, as example) you don't need to wrap it with enum, try to use it directly:

```
trait AnyTask {
    fn do_it(&self) -> Result<Success, Box<Error>>;
}
```

It makes possible to use `try!` or `.into()` everywhere. This way:

```
fn do_it(&self) -> Result<Succeed, Box<Error>> {

    let row = try!(self.database.find_last());

    if row.some_condition {
        return Err("I don't like it!".into());
    }

    try!(self.database.insert(row));

    Ok(Success)
}
```